# How to set up turtles that initially occupy random positions to the left of pxcor = -15?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to set up my turtles in NetLogo so they are in random positions to the left of `pxcor = -15`. This is the code I have right now but it's not working:

```
to setup-turtles
 create-turtles num-turtles
    ask turtles [
     set shape "circle"
     set size .5
    set xcor random-xcor > -15
    set ycor random-ycor
     set color red
     set metabolism 1 + random-float 6 ;; Zero metabolism agents are immortal
     set vision random-float 4
     set wealth random-float 20
     move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
   ]
end
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
set xcor random-xcor > -15
```

Do:

```
set xcor -15 - random-float (- min-pxcor - 14.5)
```

We start at -15, and then we move left a random amount between 0 and distance from -15 to the edge of the world. The edge of the world is 0.5 past `min-pxcor`.

Note that `>` and `<` are useful for checking whether a number is in a desired range, but there's no way to run them in reverse, so to speak, and use them to *generate* coordinates in a desired range. (Well, you could repeatedly generate a random coordinate until you get one that's in range, but it's much more efficient to generate valid coordinates directly.)